# How to pass data from fragment to adapter recycler view?

Tags: android-recyclerview, fragment, adapter

I have a fragment contain dialog which has a recycler view, after user clicked one item from the reycler view dialog, I want to pass the data and send to the main recycler view in the fragment. How can I solved this ?

**Below my Fragment**

public class UjianFragment extends BaseFragment implements UjianContract.View{

```
@Inject
UjianContract.Presenter mPresenter;

@Inject
public UjianFragment(){

}

@Override
protected int getLayoutView() {
    return R.layout.fragment_ujian;
}

@Override
protected void initView(Bundle state) {
    mPresenter.takeView(this);
    mPresenter.saveStartTime();
    mPresenter.getNumber(idMatpel,idUjian);
    LinearLayoutManager liN = new LinearLayoutManager(parentActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    rvNumber.setLayoutManager(liN);
    rvNumber.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rvNumber.setAdapter(numberAdapter);
    LinearLayoutManager lin2 = new LinearLayoutManager(parentActivity());
    rlSoal.setLayoutManager(lin2);
    rlSoal.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rlSoal.setAdapter(soalAdapter);
    countDown();

    soalAdapter.setOnClickListener(new SoalAdapter.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(String gambar,String no) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBulider = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_layout,null);
            PhotoView photoView = mView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewZoom);
            Glide.with(getContext())
                    .load(gambar)
                    .into(photoView);
            mBulider.setView(mView);
            AlertDialog mDialog = mBulider.create();
            mDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onClickJawab(String id,String jawabanUser, boolean hasil) {
            mPresenter.updateJawaban(id,jawabanUser,hasil);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClickRefreshSoal(String jenis, String idSoal) {
            if (jenis.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                mPresenter.getRefreshSoalPG(idSoal, idUjian, idMatpel);
            }else {
                mPresenter.getRefrehSoalBS(idSoal, idUjian, idMatpel);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClickRefreshJawaban(String idSoal) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onClickJawabanJD() {
            mPresenter.getJawabanJD();

            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(parentActivity());
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.item_jawabanjd);
            RecyclerView dialogRecycler = dialog.findViewById(R.id.rvJawabanMenjodohkan);

            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(parentActivity());
            dialogRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            dialogRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
            dialogRecycler.setAdapter(jawabanJDAdapter);

            jawabanJDAdapter.setOnClickListener(new JawabanJDAdapter.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClickJawaban(String jawabanJD) {
                    Toast.makeText(parentActivity(), "anda memilih " + jawabanJD, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //I want to pass this jawabanJD to the adapter
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}




@Override
public void setSuccess(boolean isShow) {
    lySuccess.setVisibility(isShow ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void reload() {
    mPresenter.getNumber(idUjian, idMatpel);
}

@Override
public void setToServer(String idUjian, String idMapel, String idSiswa, String start, String end, String valueTrue, String valueFalse, String score) {
    mPresenter.submitUjian(idUjian, idMapel, idSiswa, start, end, valueTrue, valueFalse, score);
}

@Override
public void setJawabanJD(List<JawabanJDEntity> jawabanJDEntityList) {
    jawabanJDAdapter.setGroupList(jawabanJDEntityList);
}


private void countDown() {
    int time = Integer.parseInt(timer) * 60 * 1000;

    countTimer = new CountDownTimer(time,1000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            long min = l;
            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(min), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(min) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(min)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(min) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(min)));
            tvTimer.setText(hms);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            rlSoal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mPresenter.getDataToDb(idMatpel,idUjian, type, image, soal,matpel, ujian);
            Toast.makeText(parentActivity(), "Waktu habis! Silahkan submit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    countTimer.start();
}

@Override
public void setNumber(List<SoalEntity> number) {
    numberAdapter.setGroupList(number);
    soalAdapter.setGroupList(number);
}
```

}

**and my adapter**

public class SoalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SoalAdapter.ItemVH> {

```
private  int mSelectedItem = -1;

private RadioGroup lastCheckedRadio = null;

private OnClickListener onClickListener;

private final boolean[] mCheckedStateA;
private final boolean[] mCheckedStateB;
private final boolean[] mCheckedStateC;
private final boolean[] mCheckedStateD;
private int positionl = -1;


private OnRadioItemClicked onRadioItemClicked;
private ArrayList<ObjectListItem> objectListItems;
private

List<SoalEntity> soalBeanList;
private Context context;

@Inject
public SoalAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    soalBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
    mCheckedStateA = new boolean[0];
    mCheckedStateB = new boolean[0];
    mCheckedStateC = new boolean[0];
    mCheckedStateD = new boolean[0];
}

public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
}

public void setOnRadioItemClicked(OnRadioItemClicked onRadioItemClicked){
    this.onRadioItemClicked = onRadioItemClicked;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SoalAdapter.ItemVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View root = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_soal, parent, false);
    return new SoalAdapter.ItemVH(root);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SoalAdapter.ItemVH holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(soalBeanList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return soalBeanList.size();
}

public void setGroupList(List<SoalEntity> soalBeanList1){
    soalBeanList.clear();
    soalBeanList.addAll(soalBeanList1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addLast(SoalEntity soalBean){
    soalBeanList.add(soalBean);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class ItemVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.tvItemSoalJawabanJD)
    TextView tvItemSoalJawabanJD;


    private boolean nilai = false;


    ItemVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    void bind(SoalEntity soalBean) {

        nomernya.setText(soalBean.getNoUrut());
        if (soalBean.getJenisSoal().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            rlAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rlAnswerTf.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rlAnswerMatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else if (soalBean.getJenisSoal().equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
            rlAnswer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rlAnswerTf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rlAnswerMatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if(soalBean.getJenisSoal().equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
            rlAnswer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rlAnswerTf.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rlAnswerMatch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (soalBean.getFlag().equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
            rb_e.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            jawabanE.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            jawabanE_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else if (soalBean.getFlag().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            rb_e.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            jawabanE.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            jawabanE_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else if (soalBean.getFlag().equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
            rb_d.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            jawabanD.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            jawabanD_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            rb_e.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            jawabanE.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            jawabanE_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            rb_d.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            jawabanD_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            jawabanD.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            rb_e.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            jawabanE.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            jawabanE_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (soalBean.getSoalGambar().isEmpty()||soalBean.getSoalGambar().
                equalsIgnoreCase("null")||soalBean.getSoalGambar().equalsIgnoreCase("")){

            lyNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvSoal.setText(soalBean.getSoalUjian());
            tvSoal.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            imageSoal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }else if(soalBean.getSoalUjian().isEmpty()||soalBean.getSoalUjian()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("null")||soalBean.getSoalUjian().equalsIgnoreCase("")){

            lyNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(soalBean.getSoalGambar())
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_baseline_broken_image_24)
                    .priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            loadImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            loadImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(imageSoal);
            tvSoal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            lyNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvSoal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvSoal.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            imageSoal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvSoal.setText(soalBean.getSoalUjian());
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(soalBean.getSoalGambar())
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_baseline_broken_image_24)
                    .priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            loadImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            loadImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(imageSoal);
        }

        if (soalBean.getPilA_file().isEmpty()||soalBean.getPilA_file()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("null")||soalBean.getPilA_file().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            jawabanA.setText(soalBean.getPilA());
            jawabanA.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            jawabanA_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(soalBean.getPilA_file())
                    .apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true))
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                    .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            loadImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            loadImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(jawabanA_image);
            jawabanA.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (soalBean.getPilB_file().isEmpty()||soalBean.getPilB_file()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("null")||soalBean.getPilB_file().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            jawabanB.setText(soalBean.getPilB());
            jawabanB.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            jawabanB_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(soalBean.getPilB_file())
                    .apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true))
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                    .into(jawabanB_image);
            jawabanB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (soalBean.getPilC_file().isEmpty()||soalBean.getPilC_file()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("null")||soalBean.getPilC_file().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            jawabanC.setText(soalBean.getPilC());
            jawabanC.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            jawabanC_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(soalBean.getPilC_file())
                    .apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true))
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                    .into(jawabanC_image);
            jawabanC.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (soalBean.getPilD_file().isEmpty()||soalBean.getPilD_file()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("null")||soalBean.getPilD_file().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            jawabanD.setText(soalBean.getPilD());
            jawabanD.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            jawabanD_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(soalBean.getPilD_file())
                    .apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true))
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                    .into(jawabanD_image);
            jawabanD.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (soalBean.getPilE_file().isEmpty()||soalBean.getPilE_file()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("null")||soalBean.getPilE_file().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            jawabanE.setText(soalBean.getPilE());
            jawabanE.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            jawabanE_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(soalBean.getPilE_file())
                    .apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true))
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                    .into(jawabanE_image);
            jawabanE.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        if (soalBean.getJawab().equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
            rb_a.setChecked(true);
            rb_b.setChecked(false);
            rb_c.setChecked(false);
            rb_d.setChecked(false);
            rb_e.setChecked(false);
        }else if (soalBean.getJawab().equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
            rb_a.setChecked(false);
            rb_b.setChecked(true);
            rb_c.setChecked(false);
            rb_d.setChecked(false);
            rb_e.setChecked(false);
        }else if (soalBean.getJawab().equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
            rb_a.setChecked(false);
            rb_b.setChecked(false);
            rb_c.setChecked(true);
            rb_d.setChecked(false);
            rb_e.setChecked(false);
        }else if (soalBean.getJawab().equalsIgnoreCase("D")){
            rb_a.setChecked(false);
            rb_b.setChecked(false);
            rb_c.setChecked(false);
            rb_d.setChecked(true);
            rb_e.setChecked(false);
        }else if (soalBean.getJawab().equalsIgnoreCase("E")){
            rb_a.setChecked(false);
            rb_b.setChecked(false);
            rb_c.setChecked(false);
            rb_d.setChecked(false);
            rb_e.setChecked(true);
        }else if (soalBean.getJawab().equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
            rbTrue.setChecked(true);
            rbFalse.setChecked(false);
        }else if (soalBean.getJawab().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            rbTrue.setChecked(false);
            rbFalse.setChecked(true);
        }


        rb_a.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b){
                    if (compoundButton.getId() == R.id.rb_pilih_a){
                        rb_b.setChecked(false);
                        rb_c.setChecked(false);
                        rb_d.setChecked(false);
                        rb_e.setChecked(false);
                        if(soalBean.getJawabanUjian().equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
                            nilai = true;
                        }else{
                            nilai = false;
                        }

                        if (onClickListener!=null){
                            onClickListener.onClickJawab(soalBean.getIdSoal(),"A",nilai);
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                }
            }
        });
        rb_b.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b){
                    if (compoundButton.getId() == R.id.rb_pilih_b){
                        rb_a.setChecked(false);
                        rb_c.setChecked(false);
                        rb_d.setChecked(false);
                        rb_e.setChecked(false);
                        if(soalBean.getJawabanUjian().equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
                            nilai = true;
                        }else{
                            nilai = false;
                        }

                        if (onClickListener!=null){
                            onClickListener.onClickJawab(soalBean.getIdSoal(),"B",nilai);
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                }
            }
        });
        rb_c.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b){
                    if (compoundButton.getId() == R.id.rb_pilih_c){
                        rb_a.setChecked(false);
                        rb_b.setChecked(false);
                        rb_d.setChecked(false);
                        rb_e.setChecked(false);
                        if(soalBean.getJawabanUjian().equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
                            nilai = true;
                        }else{
                            nilai = false;
                        }

                        if (onClickListener!=null){
                            onClickListener.onClickJawab(soalBean.getIdSoal(),"C",nilai);
                        }
                    }
                }else {

                }
            }
        });
        rb_d.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b){
                    if (compoundButton.getId() == R.id.rb_pilih_d){
                        rb_a.setChecked(false);
                        rb_b.setChecked(false);
                        rb_c.setChecked(false);
                        rb_e.setChecked(false);
                        if(soalBean.getJawabanUjian().equalsIgnoreCase("D")){
                            nilai = true;
                        }else{
                            nilai = false;
                        }

                        if (onClickListener!=null){
                            onClickListener.onClickJawab(soalBean.getIdSoal(),"D",nilai);
                        }
                    }
                }else {

                }
            }
        });

        rb_e.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b){
                    if (compoundButton.getId() == R.id.rb_pilih_e){
                        rb_a.setChecked(false);
                        rb_b.setChecked(false);
                        rb_c.setChecked(false);
                        rb_d.setChecked(false);
                        if (soalBean.getJawabanUjian().equalsIgnoreCase("E")){
                            nilai = true;
                        }else {
                            nilai = false;
                        }

                        if (onClickListener!=null){
                            onClickListener.onClickJawab(soalBean.getIdSoal(), "E", nilai);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        rbTrue.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b){
                    if (compoundButton.getId() == R.id.rb_pilih_true){
                        rbFalse.setChecked(false);
                        if (soalBean.getJawabanUjian().equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                            nilai = true;
                        }else {
                            nilai = false;
                        }

                        if (onClickListener!=null){
                            onClickListener.onClickJawab(soalBean.getIdSoal(), "0", nilai);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        rbFalse.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b){
                    if (compoundButton.getId() == R.id.rb_pilih_false){
                        rbTrue.setChecked(false);
                        if (soalBean.getJawabanUjian().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                            nilai = true;
                        }else {
                            nilai = false;
                        }

                        if (onClickListener!=null){
                            onClickListener.onClickJawab(soalBean.getIdSoal(), "1", nilai);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        imageSoal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (onClickListener!=null){
                    onClickListener.onClick(soalBean.getSoalGambar(),soalBean.getNoUrut());
                }
            }

        });

        tvRefreshSoal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (onClickListener!=null){
                    onClickListener.onClickRefreshSoal(soalBean.getJenisSoal(), soalBean.getIdSoal());
                }
            }
        });

        tvRefreshJawaban.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (onClickListener!=null){
                    onClickListener.onClickRefreshJawaban(soalBean.getIdSoal());
                }
            }
        });

        tvItemSoalJawabanJD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (onClickListener!=null) {
                    onClickListener.onClickJawabanJD();
                }
            }
        });
       tvItemSoalJawabanJD.setText();//This is the data result from fragemnt

    }
}

public interface  OnClickListener{
    void onClick(String gambar,String no);
    void onClickJawab(String id,String jawabanUser,boolean hasil);
    void onClickRefreshSoal(String jenis, String idSoal);
    void onClickRefreshJawaban(String idSoal);
    void onClickJawabanJD();
}

public interface  OnRadioItemClicked{
    void radioItemChecked(int itemPosition, int optNum);
}
```